# Jquery draggable collision detection bug

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, collision

There is a bug in a jquery-draggable-collision library with collision detection. Divs are overlapping even though the function for collision detection is called. I can not solve it, so if anyone can help me, i would be very grateful.
Example of this bug is here: http://jsfiddle.net/q3x8w03y/10/

```
$("#dragMe1").draggable({
    snap: ".bnh",
obstacle: ".bnh",
preventCollision: true,
containment: "#moveInHere",
start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).removeClass('bnh');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass('bnh');
    }
});
$("#dragMe2").draggable({
    snap: ".bnh",
obstacle: ".bnh",
preventCollision: true,
containment: "#moveInHere",
start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).removeClass('bnh');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass('bnh');
    }
});
```

Comment: youre collision detection is over complicated

Comment: I know :) But I just want to use the library, I haven't written it. I only need someone to help me solve the problem with overlapping within the library code that is on the jsfiddle link above.

Comment: will be easier to make your own if its just collision of two boxes, that way youll understand how it works and why it isn't working (if that happens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These checks needed to be added inside the library code (function _overlaps), so now, it all works perfectly fine http://jsfiddle.net/q3x8w03y/11/

```
if (c1.x1==c2.x1&&c1.y1==c2.y1) ||(c1.x2==c2.x2&&c1.y2==c2.y2) || (c1.x2==c2.x2&&c1.y1==c2.y1) || (c1.x1==c2.x1&&c1.y2==c2.y2) ||(c1.x1>=c2.x1&&c1.x2<=c2.x2&&c1.y1<=c2.y1&&c1.y2>=c2.y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug.  In fact, in your fiddle, the collision code is working just fine.  The problem is that, after the drag event ends, the collider is snapped to the obstacle.  Sometimes it snaps `inner` and sometimes it snaps `outer` depending on the position of the elements.

Luckily, you can define the `snapMode` option as `outer`, which will prevent the elements from overlapping post collision.  Just add the option:

```
$("#dragMe1").draggable({
        snap: ".bnh",
    snapMode: "outer",
    obstacle: ".bnh",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: "#moveInHere",
    start: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).removeClass('bnh');
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('bnh');
        }
});
$("#dragMe2").draggable({
        snap: ".bnh",
    snapMode: "outer",
    obstacle: ".bnh",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: "#moveInHere",
    start: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).removeClass('bnh');
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('bnh');
        }
});
```

Comment: There was a bug. I have just found it and solved it. Checks that are used for detecting collision with obstacles weren't complete. I added some additional conditions and solved the problem. I will post the answer in a minute. But thanks anyway! :)